# JWT contains untrusted 'aud' claim. Error on external sign in .net 7 backend Flutter frontend

Tags: .net, flutter, google-signin, webapi

I am making a mobile app with Flutter. The backend of the application has been developing in .NET 7 web API. So I try to add google sign in to both app and backend. In the app side I use google_sign_in package to get the "id_token" of the authenticated user. Also I am developing it without Firebase.

So after I get the id_token, I sent it to the backend but in the backend when I try to validate that token I get the error. I am using the official Google package "Google.Apis.Auth". Here is the validation code:

```
var googleUser = await GoogleJsonWebSignature.ValidateAsync(externalAuthDto.IdToken, new GoogleJsonWebSignature.ValidationSettings() {
    Audience = new[] { _configuration.GetValue<string>("Authentication:GoogleClientId")},
});
```

And I get "Google.Apis.Auth.InvalidJwtException: JWT contains untrusted 'aud' claim." error. I looked at the encoded JWT claims and I can see the "aud" claim is the same with the ClientID in Google Cloud Console Credentials' Web Application ClientID.

So where am I making a mistake?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, my mistake. ClientID of the Web App section on Google Cloud Console and ClientID in the appsettings were not the same. So after i found that problem, backend can verify that user.